# R filter rownames in matrix

Tags: r, row, dataframe

I have a dataframe like z:

```
z <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,
          1,0,0,0,1,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
        nrow=7,
        dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:7],NULL))

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
A    1    1    0    0
B    0    0    0    0
C    0    0    0    1
D    1    0    0    0
E    1    1    0    0
F    0    0    0    0
G    0    0    0    0
```

Now I want to remove all the rows where all the values are zero. Than the result will be:

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
A    1    1    0    0
C    0    0    0    1
D    1    0    0    0
E    1    1    0    0
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have a matrix, not a data frame :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `all()` and `apply()`:

```
z <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,
          1,0,0,0,1,0,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
          0,0,1,0,0,0,0),
        nrow=7,
        dimnames=list(LETTERS[1:7],NULL))

all.0 <- apply(z, 1, function(i) all(i==0))
z[!all.0,]
```

Result:

```
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
A    1    1    0    0
C    0    0    0    1
D    1    0    0    0
E    1    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 3):

And also if all element is positive numeric, you can do by using `rowSums`:

```
> z[rowSums(z)>0,]
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
A    1    1    0    0
C    0    0    0    1
D    1    0    0    0
E    1    1    0    0
```

this is little bit tricky, and @Vincent's approach is more general.